# How to detect double click event on google chart (pie chart)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

How do I detect a double click event on google charts? Here is my code:

```
    var options = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    console.log(chart);
    chart.is3D = true;
    chart.draw(data, options);
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'click', function(e){
        console.log(e);
        console.log(chart.getSelection());
        var data = chart.getSelection();
        if(data.length > 0) {
            alert(0);
            chart.setSelection([]);
        }
        //window.open("http://classicmayank.limewebs.com", "mywindow1", "status=1,width=350,height=150");
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

I know it is an old question but I have tried a little hack how to detect a double-click. Just by measuring it. It is for sure not a nice or robust solution but it seems to work.

```
var firstClick = 0;
var secondClick = 0;

google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'click', function () {
    var date = new Date();
    var millis = date.getTime();

    if (millis - secondClick > 1000) {        
        // add delayed check if a single click occured
        setTimeout(function() {
            // no second click fast enough, it is a single click
            if (secondClick == 0) {
                alert("click");
            }
        }, 250);
    }

    // try to measure if double-clicked
    if (millis - firstClick < 250) {        
        firstClick = 0;
        secondClick = millis;

        alert("doubleClick");

    } else {
        firstClick = millis;
        secondClick = 0;
    }
});
```

JSFiddle to it is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cczskgpw/2/).

Comment: One drawback is slowing-down the response on a single-click (by the 250ms waiting on the potential second click). I have no idea how to improve it but UI systems like Windows seem to have a solution. There is no delay by a single-click.

Answer (score 1):

I did the following

```
    var clicks = 0;

    function selectHandler() {

      clicks++;

      setTimeout(function() {
          if (clicks >= 2) {
              alert("double click");

          }
          clicks = 0;
      }, 250);



    }

    //bind the select event with chart
    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', selectHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a little late i guess but use something along the lines of

```
   google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', columnselectHandler)
   var status = 0;

   function columnselectHandler(e) {
            var selection = chart.getSelection();
            var selectedItem = selection[0];
            var data2 = getDDData(k);
            var columndata = [] 
      if (selectedItem) {
    if (status == 0){
    var name = data.getValue(selectedItem.row, 0);
    columndata[0] =  data2[0] 
    columndata[1] =  data2[selectedItem.row+1]                          
              var chartData = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(columndata);
        chart.draw(chartData, {width: 1200, height:500}, options);
        var button = document.getElementsByClassName("backToMain")[0];        
          button.setAttribute("id",chartType)
         button.setAttribute("style","display:inline; margin-top:150px; font-size:30px; position:absolute;")`
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this by listening to the double click event of chart_div (the container).

conatiner = document.getElementById('chart_div');

container.addEventListener('dblclick', (e)=>console.log('double clicked'));

Answer (score -3):

Jquery provides a double click event that you can use. As you can see in the example here:

```
$("p").dblclick( function () { alert("Hello World!"); });
```

The jQuery page where you can find more it's here: http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/

Comment: No dude actually google charts display in an iframe and we cannot make it clickable thats why i am asking here what to do?

Comment: Well if you only need to double click the chart you can use this to double click the iframe. Maybe i got it wrong but i see you already have an event so this double click thing should be the same thing.

Comment: Dude i am searching from today's morning and got nothing about this i think dblclick event is not supported in google charts.

Comment: Yea, I'm having the same issue. I wish it had click and dblclick.